# The expected value for a function of an exponential r.v X

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

For an exponential r.v $X$  with parameter $\lambda >0$, I try to find the expected value of $e^{X/2}$.

I think this is possible through the moment generating function but I want to do it following the definition so

$$\mathbb{E} \left(e^{X/2}\right) = \lambda \int_0^{\infty} e^{x/2}e^{-\lambda x} dx=  \lambda \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\frac{x}{2}(2\lambda -1)} dx = \dots $$

Then how to continue and which constraints to consider?

Comment: $$ \int_0^\infty e^{-ax}dx = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{a} & ,\textrm{if }a >0 \\ +\infty&, \textrm{otherwise}\end{cases} $$

Comment: @ChargeShivers very clever, straight from the exponential pdf identity, very nice.

Answer (score 2):

$$\mathbb{E}[e^{x}] = \lambda \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x(2\lambda - 1)/2} \mathop{dx} = \lambda\left(\frac{e^{-x(2\lambda - 1)/2}}{(1-2\lambda)/2}\right)\Big|_{0}^{\infty} =  \boxed{\frac{2}{2\lambda - 1}}$$

The constraints are $\lambda > 1/2$.

Comment: yes thank it is a normal integration! it is my mistake but anyway thanks a lot

Comment: Yup, just normal integration. There are no tricks here.